# log / capture all the queries executed in drupal

Tags: hooks

I want to log / capture all the queries executed by the drupal?
update, select, insert any query,
is there any hook or what will be the method to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You want [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel).

It has a lot of helpful tools for Drupal developers, including a helper function to print a summary of all database queries for each page request at the bottom of each page. The summary includes how many times each query was executed on a page (shouldn't run same query multiple times), and how long each query took.

Comment: tried Devel, it is giving the front end queries in debug mod, only select and update to cache table

Answer (score 0):

Note that Drupal can generate a lot of queries for a single page view. So if you don't want to be doing anything programmatic with the queries then maybe a better option is to just log everything with the [MySQL query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html).

Comment: mainly want to keep track on insert and update queries